# How to clone partially using TortoiseHG "Clone" on bitbucket?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I want to clone part of repository to non-tip changeset, so I use TortoiseHG -> Clone command, enter commit URL and clone. For some reason I get the clone to the last changeset, not that I wanted to clone.

How to clone to old changeset?

I've read that I can do this with git commands. Can I do it with TortoiseHG?

Answer (score 3):

1. You clone not "commit", but "repository"
2. If you want to have partial clone, you have to read `hg help clone`
3. Procedure and syntax is common to all and any repositories, unrelated to BitBucket

> To pull only a subset of changesets, specify one or more revisions
>   identifiers with -r/--rev or branches with -b/--branch. The resulting 
>   clone will contain only the specified changesets and their ancestors.

`hg clone -r <ID> SRC`

`hg help urls` suggests second form of command

`hg clone SRC#ID`

**GUI-way**

In case of pure GUI in TortoiseHG "Clone" dialogue, expand "Options" enable "Clone to revision" and define this revision ID

[image: Clone]

Comment: @LazyBadgger, can I do all this in TortoiseHG?